# JAX-RS, RestEasy: No session cookie

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, jboss7.x

Folks,

Used to be that when you hit a servlet/jsp, the app server would automatically start a session. It would put a session cookie in the first dynamic response that would get tracked throughout.

I have a rest backend and I notice that no session cookies are being traded. So I manually add code to send the JSESSIONID cookie:

```
@Context 
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
// ...
@GET
@Path( "/{rcpGuid}" )
public Response myMethod( ... )
{
    final HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
    final String sSessionId = session.getId();
    ...
    return Response.status( Response.Status.SEE_OTHER ).
        location( redirectUrl ).cookie( new NewCookie( "JSESSIONID", sSessionId ) );
}
```

Now this is causing 2 copies of the JSESSIONID cookie being returned where before there was no Set-Cookie header. This is what I see now in my browser's inspector:

```
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=sdm-Q1P6pRoQbKd4-9cJylGb; Path=/nn, JSESSIONID=sdm-Q1P6pRoQbKd4-9cJylGb; Version=1
```

I don't care as long as this would work. But unfortunately, when my browser requests the URL being redirected to (notice that the response is "SEE_OTHER"), that request does not bear the session id. This causing my app to not function right.

Any insights?

Comment: What is your client side framework?  It's possible that the client is ignoring/rejecting the session id sent by your server.  I only mention this because I use the Jersey client API and it uses Java's cookie mechanism under the hood which rejects all cookies out of the box.

Comment: A REST design is stateless. Why do you need a cookie? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Used to be that when you hit a servlet/jsp, the app server would automatically start a session. It would put a session cookie in the first dynamic response that would get tracked throughout.

The app server doesn't create a session until `httpRequest.getSession()` is called.

> I have a rest backend and I notice that no session cookies are being traded. So I manually add code to send the JSESSIONID cookie:

In your example, you call `getSession()` and create a separate `jsessionid` cookie. That would explain why you have two cookies. If you do neither, you wont have a `jessionid` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a REST back-end, so you should not have JSESSIONID cookie and keep your back-end endpoints as Stateless.

All informations required to get a result from one of your web service should be contained in the request to the web service. A web service is idempotent.